# how to check stats for multiple file in directory and send as json to client?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

Lets assume i have three files in directory i want to check stats for all these files and send birthtimes to client ,Its always returning one file stats as you can see in data. How can i get stats for all files from directory ?

app.js

```
  var path = './logs/ditLogs'
  fs.stat(path, function (err,stats) {
        console.log('STATS',stats);
        fileData.birthtime = stats.birthtime;
        //callback(stats.mtime);
    });
```

data

```
{ birthtime: Tue Jul 12 2016 09:33:14 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  filename: ['server.log', 'server1.log' ] }
```

Comment: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async library is the way to go. http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

I would suggest something like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const async = require('async'); // install with: npm install --save async

var dirPath = './logs/ditLogs';
// this will get you list of all files. in directory
var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
var objToReturn = {};
// then using async do like this
async.eachSeries(files, function (file, callback) {
    var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
    fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
        // write stats data into objToReturn 
        callback();
   });
}, function(err) {
    // final callback when all files completed here send objToReturn to client
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: stats to objTOReturn i should write into array like ObjToReturn.statsArray = [] ?

Comment: You can write in anything you want. It's just example.. You can even write in string. Stats is object with file statistic. So you get data from there and push into array of into object and then return that result to user.

Comment: No luck i used your approach but still only getting stats for one file

Comment: Imposible..You doing something wrong in routes or in final callback..Check callback function names..Just copy code in some file run it..and console log results. You should see all file stats... And also make sure you actualy have more than 1 file in directory. I try this code in my PC all works. Also maybe show route that runs this code and sends results into user.